# ISession +NHibernate (no session or session was closed)

Tags: c#, winforms, nhibernate

**Em um projeto WindowsForms**

Utilizando padrao repository, em uma classe generica tenho o seguinte método:

```
    public IList<T> Listar() {
        using (ISession session = SessionFactory.Instance.GetSession()) {
            return (from c in session.Query<T>() select c).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Ele funciona normalmente e fecha a session(imagino que seja a forma correta).

Carrego o resultado em um datagridview e ao tentar acessar objetos mais complexos (com referencia a outras classes) recebo a exception `no session or session was closed`, pois estou usando LazyLoad por padrão.

Existe alguma forma de contornar este problema, considerando manter LazyLoad?

**Singleton de SessionFactory, que retorna sempre uma nova session**

```
public class SessionFactory {
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Instancia da classe SessionFactory
    /// </summary>
    private static SessionFactory _instance;
    private SessionFactory() {
    }
    public static SessionFactory Instance {
        get {
            return _instance ?? (_instance = new SessionFactory());
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Instancia singleton de objeto do tipo ISessionFactroy
    /// </summary>
    private ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;
    private ISessionFactory GetSessionFactory {
        get {
            return _sessionFactory ?? (_sessionFactory = BuildFactory());
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Método que retorna objeto ISessionFactory
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private ISessionFactory BuildFactory() {
        try {
            IPersistenceConfigurer configDB = PostgreSQLConfiguration
                    .PostgreSQL82
                    .ConnectionString(ConnectionString)
                    .ShowSql()
                    .FormatSql()
                    .UseReflectionOptimizer();

            FluentConfiguration FConf = Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(configDB)
                .Mappings(c => c.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<System.Retaguarda.Map.UsuarioMap>())
                .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaUpdate(cfg).Execute(false, true));

            return FConf.BuildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine("Erro ao carregar configurações do banco de dados\nDica: Verifique as configurações de conexão\n" + ex.Message + "\n" + ex.InnerException);
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    public ISession GetSession() {
        return GetSessionFactory.OpenSession();
    }

}
```

Comment: Andei lendo por ai que talvez Ninject possa gerenciar a session e resolver este problema, só não encontrei como isso é possivel

Comment: Se você tirar o `using` o que acontece?

Comment: Ai eu teria que iniciar a session na instancia da classe, o que manteria ela aberta causando outros problemas, como o mesmo objeto em duas session diferentes (já apanhei bastante rsrs)

Comment: depende ... agora que eu vi que está falando de form isso deve ser colocado em tag melhor compreensão. Se pode rodar o dispose depois da linha do grid por exemplo! rapaz depende!

Comment: `SessionFactory.Instance` isso é um `singleton`? coloque a sua classe inteira!

Comment: opa, adicionada SessionFactory, ela é um singleton, porém retorna sempre um ISession novo.
Seria correto eu manter no form o controle da session?

Comment: Você pretende usar `LazyLoading` sem ter uma *session* aberta?

Comment: **opa, adicionada SessionFactory, ela é um `singleton`, porém retorna sempre um ISession novo** então ele não é `singleton` Singleton me garante uma instância de um classe. Eu trabalharia com instâncias e quando o form for fechado dava um `dispose`, `close`. Poderia até trabalhar com singleton `ISession` em seu projeto utilizando ela nos forms. Tem algumas formas de implementar isso tudo vai depender do contexto

Comment: Então, com a session aberta direto (singleton) funciona perfeitamente o LazyLoading, porém se eu faço uma pesquisa e carrego o grid, ele fica com os objetos carregados... (se nesse tempo alguém alterar alguma informação em outra maquina no banco de dados) por mais que eu pesquise novamente, ele não atualiza as informações no meu grid, a não ser que eu feche a session e abra novamente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usei a interface IDisposable e estou controlando a session no form:

**Repository:**

```
public class Repository<T> : IDisposable, IRepository<T> where T : class {
    protected ISession session = SessionFactory.Instance.GetSession();

    public void Gravar(T entidade) {
        using (ITransaction transacao = session.BeginTransaction()) {
        }
    }

    public void Excluir(T entidade) {
        using (ITransaction transacao = session.BeginTransaction()) {
        }
    }

    public T PesquisarPorId(int Id) {
        return session.Get<T>(Id);
    }

    public IList<T> Listar() {
        return (from c in session.Query<T>() select c).ToList();
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        session.Close();
    }
}
```

**Form:**

```
    private void PanelCrud_Disposed(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        IDisposable disposable = Repositorio as IDisposable;
        if (disposable != null)
            disposable.Dispose();
    }
```

Desta forma, tenho um SessionFactory singleton e para cada form inicio uma session que sera fechada no evento Dispose()